# Comment field too short to scroll

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On iOS 8, with the new predictive text type thing, the comment field can now be squashed to a single line high - which makes it very difficult to scroll.

[image]

From what I can see, this is cause by the predictive-text-block taking space from the comment-block, rather than the background-block. Through experimentation, I found you can swipe collapse the predictive block, although this isn't immediately obvious when it's open by default (I think!)

This is iPhone 4s, iOS 8.1.2, and app v1.2.1.

Comment: Taking a look at this

Comment: Interesting, I have only seen this reproduce on an iPhone *4S*

Comment: @Arie *facepalm* 4S is what I have - sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in **beta version 1.2.0.174**.

The issue here was a calculation we do to determine how much extra "reading" space we should leave above the comment view so that users can scroll the question area while drafting a comment. This wasn't taking into account shorter screens like the 4S has.